# How do I add destructuring here in the case

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, destructuring

I learn React and JavaScript. I stumbled on this Eslint suggest I do destructuring like the image warning suggest but where do I add that. I try like `const { errorComponent }= props;` but that did not work inside a `const`

[image]

The code:

```
import '../../styles/error.scss';

const Error = props => (
    <div className="error-message">
        {props.errorComponent ? <props.errorComponent {...props} /> : <p className="alert">Unable to preview file</p>}
    </div>
);

export default Error;
```

Comment: You have a quick-fix option there, also you can google the warning: https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/destructuring-assignment.md, moreover, you should use capital letters when rendering custom components, so `const { errorComponent } = props;` should work

Comment: All answers are good actually thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additionaly to my comment, your components might look something like this:

```
const Error = ({ errorComponent: Component, ...props }) => (
  <div className="error-message">
    {Component ? (
      <Component {...props} />
    ) : (
      <p className="alert">Unable to preview file</p>
    )}
  </div>
);
```

A better option is to use `children` prop instead.

```
const Error = ({ children }) => (
  <div className="error-message">
    {children || <p className="alert">Unable to preview file</p>}
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you can destructure it look like this

```
const Error = props => {
  const {errorComponent, otherProperty} = props
  return (<div className="error-message">
      {errorComponent ? <errorComponent {otherProperty} /> : <p className="alert">Unable to preview file</p>}
  </div>)
}
  


export default Error;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach.

```
  const Error = ({ errorComponent, ...props }) => {
        const ErrorComponent = errorComponent;
        return (<div className="error-message">
            {errorComponent ? <ErrorComponent {...props} /> : <p className="alert">Unable to preview file</p>}
        </div>)
      }
```

**`<errorComponent>`** - it won't work as expected because all the custom components should start with block letter(if not, react will consider it as in-build Html tag)